# Error probability of BPSK with intersymbol interference

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, bit-error

Consider an AWGN channel with BPSK modulation. Assume that

1. the information bits are i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter 0<p<1,
2. we have ISI due to a timing offset at the transmitter, and
3. the decoder votes for +1 is the received signal is positive and votes for -1 otherwise, i.e., the usual ML decoder.

Are you aware of any literature investigating the probability of error in this setting? (note that p is not necessarily 0.5.)

Comment: unless p=0.5, you'd be wrong to use "the usual ML decoder", you need to use MAP.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If by "being wrong", you mean "not optimal", yes, I agree it is not optimal, but in this context, optimality is not the main concern.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider an AWGN channel

but

> we have ISI due to a timing offset at the transmitter

just a notational convention: that's an ISI channel, not an AWGN channel anymore (we use the term "AWGN channel" specifically for channels where, end-to-end, we really only see uncorrelated additive Gaussian noise; it's kind of the "signal word" for "add Gaussian white noise to input signal, done")

> the decoder votes for +1 is the received signal is positive and votes for -1 otherwise, i.e., the usual ML decoder.

Unless \$p=0.5\$, you'd be wrong to use "the usual ML decoder", you need to use MAP.

But assuming you still do that, I know literature; actually, it was the the "communications engineering 1" scriptum when I was a student, and when I was holding the hall lectures on the topic.

So, any standard communications engineering textbook would do: Proakis, Sklar, Kammmeyer… I bought a cheap used Proakis "Digital Communications", third edition, from a second-hand store. You'll find this in the index for "Error Probability: Binary signals".

But it really takes no big literature, this fits in an answer quite nicely:

Let's ignore ISI at first. Your noise is additive and uncorrelated and normally distributed, so the PDF for the received signal when -1 was sent, \$f_{R|S}(r| s=-1)\$ just happens to be that of a Normal variable of the noise variance \$\sigma^2 = E_b/N_0\$ and locus -1, \$\mathcal N(-1, \sigma^2)\$. If +1 was sent, \$f_{R|S}(r| s=+1)\$ is that of a Normal variable \$\mathcal N(+1, \sigma^2)\$.

Now, an error happens with the probability

\begin{align}
P_E &= p_s(+1) \cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 f_{R|S}(r| s=+1) + p_S(-1) \cdot \int\limits_0^{\infty} f_{R|S}(r| s=-1),
\end{align}
i.e., when you've transmitted a +1 and erroneously received a value < 0, or vice versa, when you transmitted a -1 and received a value > 0.

Because your \$f_{R|S}\$ are just shifted scaled standardnormal variables, we can replace these integrals over the PDFs with CDFs of the standard normal:

\begin{align}
P_E &= p_S(+1) \cdot \Phi(-1/\sigma) + p_S(-1) \cdot (1-\Phi(+1/\sigma)) & \|\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)\\
&=p_S(+1) \cdot (1-\Phi(1/\sigma)) + p_S(-1) \cdot(1-\Phi(1/\sigma))\\
&=(1-\Phi(1/\sigma))(p_S(+1) + p_S(-1))\\
&=(1-\Phi(1/\sigma))\cdot 1\\
&=1 - \Phi(1/\sigma)
\end{align}

So far so good for the basic lecture level:

Now, you *do* have ISI. Bummer! Luckily, symbols are mutually indepedent (I hope!), so that any given additive (or subtractive, depending on the signa of the other symbol) term from the pulse shape of neighboring symbol is equally likely.

Let's assume for a second that you know the timing error, \$\Delta \tau\$. Then you can simply "look up" in the pulse shape what the contribution of a neighboring "+1" symbol is, \$h(T-\Delta\tau)\$. So, if only one neighbor contributes, you just extend the calculation above into four cases, instead of two cases for a) \$T=+1\$, and b) \$T=-1\$, you go and have four cases, a) \$T_{-1} = +1, T_{0} = +1\$, b) \$T_{-1} = +1, T_{0} = -1\$, c) \$T_{-1} = -1, T_{0} = +1\$, and d) \$T_{-1} = -1, T_{0} = -1\$, with probabilities to occur in the symbol stream of \$p^2\$, \$p(1-p)\$, \$(1-p)p\$ and \$(1-p)^2\$, respectively.

For a) instead of shifting the normal variable to +1, you shift it to \$+h(\tau)+h(T-\tau)\$; for b), you shift it to \$-h(\tau)+h(T-\tau)\$, and so on. Then, as before, you weigh all four error probabilities with their occurrence probabilities, and sum them, and get an error probability.

This is fine for small timing errors and short pulse shapes, but the number of cases you get is \$2^K\$, with \$K\$ being the symbols that affect any received values (including the "correct" one). If that gets unwieldy, stochastics has another trick up its sleeve: The central limit theorem (to be precise, the *Lyapunov CLT*), which allows us to simply model the sum of pulse-shape weighted independent symbols as normally distributed with the sum variance, i.e., the sum of squared absolute values from the pulse shape. Yay? Yay! That's easy to compute; for a fine range of sensible \$\Delta \tau\$ you just compute

$$\sigma_h^2(\Delta\tau) := \sum\limits_{n=-\infty, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots, \infty} |h(n\cdot T -\Delta\tau)|^2$$

and get the variance of a Gaussian variable that you can just add to the AWGN. And: the sum of two Gaussian variables is again Gaussian distributed, with the sum variance! So, you just find the average of your ISI influence \$\sigma_h^2(\Delta\tau)\$ (typically, by numerical averaging over \$\Delta\tau\$, but if you have a closed form of \$h(\tau)\$, be your own guest and do it analytically), and use that to increase your noise variance, and then calculate as if you had no ISI at all. **This, however, assumes long pulse shapes**; Lyapunov's central limit theorem for independent, but not identically distributed variables does not converge as quickly to a normal distribution as the "classical" CLT.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Regarding the notation: I have seen papers in this context using theses terms "AWGN channel with ISI", "AWGN/ISI", "ISI in AWGN channel", "AWGN channel with intersymbol interference". (in IEEE TIT, TCOM, etc. if needed, I can share.) continued...

Comment: Regarding the Lyapunov CLT, or even the weaker condition Lindeberg-Feller, the condition of variance converging to infinity cannot be satisfied for example if we use the sinc function as the pulse shape, hence, Gaussian approximation fails.

Comment: There are quite a few papers investigating the error probability when p=1/2. The exact pdf of the ISI cannot be always obtained, so they rely on moment spaces, or Gram-Charlier expansion to obtain upper/lower bounds on the error probability.

Comment: So, if we use sinc pulse, i.e., ideal bandlimitted version, CLT fails, and there are bounds only for p=1/2 as far as I am aware. So, I was wondering if anyone has seen any results, upper/lower bounds when p is not necessarily 1/2.

Comment: Of course using large deviations techniques, we can get bounds on the tail of the pdf of ISI, for example the application of Chernoff bounds shows that the pdf (centered around its mean) is sub-Gaussian, but that's not very helpful for this purpose.

Comment: Needless to say that one can always apply Berry-Esseen's theorem, the non-identical summands version, to obtain how far the CDF of ISI is from a standard normal, but after some back-of-the-envelope calculations, it turns out to be a rather loose bound.

Comment: @Ben yep :) Well spotted; I was very sloppy in my notation: of course a finite sum of non-Gaussians has not converged to a Gaussian, and as I tacitly omitted was that I can't prove Lyapunov's condition to hold for arbitrary infinitely long pulse shapes; haven't tried to do that for a sinc, but I simply take your word that it fails. *However*, you can get pretty good error bounds that way for things like long RRC pulses; and I have a sketch of an idea why the sinc is especially conductive to a different kind of argument:

Comment: ah no, that doesn't work. Hm.

Comment: By the way, if you understand your pulse shape to be unknown, this is just identical to the BPSK estimation problem in a multipath channel (with AWGN).

Comment: Thanks. regarding your last comment: in that multipath channel, what technical tool is needed for the analysis of probability of error?CLT?

Comment: That kind of depends on how you model the distribution of the channel taps (in the discrete case, which I mostly care about); the most typical model there is Rayleigh-distributed amplitudes and uniformly distributed phases, and as you can see from that, the underlying idea is complex circularly normal distributions, which are physically quite sensible for environment where many different (or even a smooth continuum) path lengths happen, so yeah, the model inherent to what you apply is based in CLT / physics. Then, you find the expectation of the ISI effect. The modelling might be different,

Comment: the application might be the same as in your case.

Comment: Yes, but as far as a sinc pulse is concerned with i.i.d. Bernoulli bits with parameter p, the problem is not identical to "the BPSK estimation problem in a multipath channel (with AWGN)", please correct me if I'm wrong. At least I couldn't find any literature finding even bounds on the error in this setting.